# Sync a self hosted Seafile server with an external Owncloud Server

Tags: owncloud

I'm running a raspberry pi 2 with the latest Raspbian image.
I installed a Seafile Server there and sync my devices with it, which works just fine! But now I want to sync the data with an external OwnCloud Server.

Im currently have installed Seafile client and OwncloudClient on the device I use the most. There I have the Data 2 times, which are synced ONE-WAY from the Seafile-Folder to the Owncloud Folder via rsync.

But my goal is to do this on the raspberry pi! But for this I would need to Install the Seafile and Owncloud client there. Is there an opportunity to do this wihout installing a GUI on the raspberry, or is it even possible to run these clients an an arm processor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution myself:

it is possible to mount the seafile data with `seaf-fuse start /mnt/seafile` do any directory.

then I mounted the owncloud folder via `webdav` these folder with rsync.

takes a while but it works